# Java сортировка по количеству букв

Tags: java, строки, сортировка

Всем привет. Я относительно недавно начал изучать Java. Есть некоторые затруднения. У меня задание отсортировать строчку по количеству букв в ней используя StringBuilder, к примеру `hhhheeeeelllo` после сортировки должно быть таким `eeeeehhhhlllo`. Но у меня иначе к примеру `hhhhhhheeeeeelllllllllo` консоль выводит мне это `hhhhhheeeeeehlllllllllо`. Также нельзя использовать коллекци. Я представляю как должно выглядеть на С++ и попытался также сделать, но так у меня вообще не работает поэтому я его за комментировал. Помогите пожалуйста. Заранее благодарен.

Цикл должен выглядеть так, как я понимаю

```
for(int i = 1; i<s.length(); i++) {
  for(int j = s.length()-1; j>=i; j--) {
    if(word[j-1] > word[j]) {
      ....
    }
  }
}
```

А вот собственно мой код

```
  class StringBuilder {
      public void sorting_stringBuilder(String s) {
          int i,j;
          char temp;
          java.lang.StringBuilder news = new java.lang.StringBuilder(s);

          for(i=1; i<s.length(); i++) {
            for(j=s.length() - 1; j >= i; j--) {
               if((int) news.charAt(j-1) > (int) news.charAt(j)) {
                 temp = news.charAt(i);
                 //news.charAt(j-1) = news.charAt(j);
                 //news.charAt(j) = temp;
                 news.setCharAt(i, news.charAt(j-1));
                 news.setCharAt(j-1, temp);
               }
            }
          }
          System.out.println("s is = "+news);
       }
  }

  public class Laba3 {
      public static void main(String[] args) {
          StringBuilder sb = new StringBuilder();
          sb.sorting_stringBuilder("hhhhhhheeeeeelllllllllo");
      }
  }
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

А задача не простая. То что вы делаете - это что-то вроде сортировку пузрьком, но по алфавиту. По факту вам нужно подсчитать количество вхождений каждого символа в строке и потом воссоздать строку заново.

Конечно проще всего это было бы сделать с помощью Map или даже Stream из java8. Но раз использовать коллекции нельзя...

Я думаю по проcтому это невозможно, из-за того, что нам нужно держать соответсвие между "символом - сколько раз встречается".

То что я могу предложить это вот это:

```
String input = "hhhheeello";
int[] symbols = new int[256];

for (byte current: input.getBytes(StandardCharsets.UTF_8))
    symbols[current]++;

StringBuilder builder = new StringBuilder();
// Аля сортировка подсчетом
for (int count = 1; count < input.length(); count++)
    // Смортрим какие символы есть с количеством count
    for (char charCode = 0; charCode < symbols.length; charCode++)
        if (symbols[charCode] == count)
            for (int i = 0; i < count; i++) builder.append(charCode);

System.out.println(builder.toString());
```

Это лишь один из возможных извращенных вариантов. Конечно его можно и улучшить. Скажем можно от StringBuilder вообще избавится. Но все равно проблемы очевидны, и для больших строк будет работать плохо. Да и в любом случае выглядит страшненько - вариант на коллекциях будет попроще и читабельнее.

Comment: огромное Вам спасибо

Answer (score 1):

Задачка понравилась. Решил через определение компаратора.

```
String input = "hhhheeeeelllo";
char[] chars = input.toCharArray();
Function<char[], Character[]> toCharacterArray = chars1 -> {
  Character[] characters = new Character[chars1.length];
  for (int i = 0; i < chars1.length; i++)
    characters[i]  = (Character) chars1[i];
  return characters;
};
Character[] characters = toCharacterArray.apply(chars);
Function<Character, Integer> charCount = c1 -> input.length() - input.replaceAll(c1.toString(), "").length();
Arrays.sort(characters);
Arrays.sort(characters, (c1, c2) -> charCount.apply(c2) - charCount.apply(c1));
StringBuilder sb = new StringBuilder();
for (char c : characters) {
  sb.append(c);
}
System.out.println(sb.toString());
```

Answer (score 0):

Если в лоб - то можно использовать что-то подобное:

```
public static void main(String[] args) {
    StringBuilder s = new StringBuilder("hhhheeeeelllo ");
    System.out.println(sort(s));
}

public static StringBuilder sort(StringBuilder sb) {
    char[] chars = sb.toString().toCharArray();
    Arrays.sort(chars);
    return new StringBuilder(new String(chars));
}
```

Comment: оно ведь не сортирует по количеству, оно сортирует по алфавиту